# Promise values being pushed into array in wrong order

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to push values into an array, however the values are being pushed in the wrong order.

```
//Returns ongoing stream of the decibels in the room 
async getNoise() {
  let subscription = this.dbMeter.start().subscribe(data => {
    this.noiseDb = data;
    return data;
  });
}​ //Returns your current location 
getPosition() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej);
  });
}

async startTimer() {
  this.interval = setInterval(async() => {

    interface pos {
      coords ? : any,
    }

    var position: pos = await this.getPosition(); // wait for getPosition to complete

    this.getNoise();

    objects.push({
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      long: position.coords.longitude,
      noise: this.noiseDb
    });
  }, 500);

}
```

This works fine when there's a 2 second delay, however when there's a one second delay, or half a second delay as shown above, the values get pushed into the array in the wrong order and the same value is used for multiple entries. For example,

```
[{"lat":55.7558,"long":4.4784,"noise":45.58059,"time":"1.01"},
{"lat":55.7558,"long":4.4784,"noise":45.58059,"time":"2.01"}, 
{"lat":55.7558,"long":4.4784,"noise":40.197384,"time":"4.01"}, 
{"lat":55.7558,"long":4.4784,"noise":40.197384,"time":"3.01"}]
```

I believe I need to use Promise.all() but I'm unsure how I could implement this. Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: What is ```this.noiseDb``` and why aren't you awaiting when calling to ```this.getNoise()```?

Comment: noiseDb is just a variable I initialised at the start and whenever I await this.getNoise(), the value that's pushed to the array is always undefined

Comment: And when do you expect that getCurrentPosition gives you a different value?

Comment: We're assuming the user is moving, e.g. running or cycling. So every 500ms getCurrentPosition should return a different value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because async calls are not waiting for pervious one to complete before execution. That's why they are async. They usually used for IO operations which takes time to be executed. Instead of waiting 0.5-1 seconds each time the async method will not block the thread so other calls will be made during async function is executing (eg: while the file is loading, or getting geolocation browser can update UI smoothly).

In your case, you're calling async function each 500ms. As I said before async functions aren't waiting for the previous one to complete. So If the second call executed before the first one your list order will be incorrect. To fix that issue I suggest writing your code like below:

```js
let running = true;

startTimer() {
  if (!running) return;

  setTimeout(async() => {
    interface pos {
      coords ? : any,
    }

    var position: pos = await this.getPosition(); // wait for getPosition to complete

    this.getNoise();

    objects.push({
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      long: position.coords.longitude,
      noise: this.noiseDb
    });

    startTimer();
  }, 500);
}

startTimer();
```

To start timer set `running = true` then call `startTimer()`. To stop running timer just set `running = false`.

I used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` because I will re-fetch the next geolocation only after I finished fetching the current one.

Comment: I agree with Misir Jafarov in the root problem: you are using async thinking synchronously. I strongly disagree in the proposed solution: what is the point of doing async calls and block all the logic until each one of the calls has been resolved?

Comment: @adripanico I did not get you. Did I write something wrong? The given code is not blocking the logic. setTimeout is also async call tho.

Comment: What solution would you purpose, @adripanico? I attempted the solution given above, however startTimer() at the bottom doesn't actually seem to run at all so the values are only  being pushed into the array once. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: I am firstly trying to understand what are you attempting to do with that code. Please answer to my comment in the question.

Comment: I did not tested my code because it needs more details to test. It's just an example

Comment: @adripanico I think he wanted to get geolocation and push it into an array every 500ms. But I do not know what is for `getNoise()`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. getNoise() starts a stream of data and sets this.noiseDb to whatever the value of the data is (stream of data is a continuous incoming stream of the noise level in the room e.g. 50dB, 55.5 dB etc. I then want to run startTimer, which gets the the current location of the user, and then pushes whatever the coordinates of the user are at that current time(we're assuming the user is moving so different entries will have different coordinates) and noise level which coincides with that time to an object every 500ms. I hope this clears things up, thanks again!

Comment: @NickM The problem is that `this.getPosition` is an async call that is not guaranteed to resolved within 500ms. In that case, your array will be in the wrong order.

Comment: I suggest you to use [Geolocation.watchPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) api instead of querying for each .5s store resolved time and data in the array and calculate the required value with stored data.

Comment: Actually, in devices with GPS, the call to getCurrentPosition can get up to 1 minute to be resolved.